# Grass-gis grid and Shapefile grid: what's the difference?

Tags: r, grass-gis, vector-grid, grass-7.0, grass-7.2

I have a raster map with trees in grass (1 and NULL value) for 6m resolution. I would like to aggregate this data in a grid with a resolution of 250m.

For that I have created a grid with `v.mkgrid` and using `v.rast.stats` I what count pixel for each grid cell.

It works perfectly in 50 min for a grid of 81323 cells.

To compare with MODIS data I have used R and create a grid with the exact extend and resolution of my MODIS value

```
grid <- raster(extent(one.ym))
res(grid) <- res(one.ym)[1]
proj4string(grid)<-proj4string(one.ym)
gridpolygon <- rasterToPolygons(grid)
writeOGR(obj = gridpolygon,dsn="/home/user/",layer="mygrid_modis.shp", driver = "ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer = T
```

Once my grid imported in GRASS-GIS I run `v.rast.stats` but I spend 6h and it is still running.

What's the difference between shapefile grid and Grid from v.mkgrid? How can I improve my shapefile grid time?

By the way, I have created my grid in grass72 using `r.to.vect` on my landsat raster. It doesn't make a difference in CPU time. In both case I have defined the region size and resolution on my raster.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to set the [computational region](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region) to the raster map prior to the call of v.rast.stats. For this, see also the Wiki: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/R_statistics/rgrass7#Querying_maps

You could also use [r.in.xyz](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.in.xyz.html) if you need to just count occurrences with "method=n". It is super-fast. The original data first write out with e.g. [r.out.xyz](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.out.xyz.html).

Comment: Thank you for the resource on computational region, but using `r.to.vect` on my landsat raster I have a grid with good extent... and it does not make faster the `v.rast.stats` function. I don't understand this CPU difference!

Comment: Well,  v.rast.stats calculates univariate statistics from a raster map based on a vector map and uploads statistics to new attribute columns. Hence a lot of database traffic is involved. But I'll edit my answer for another idea.

Comment: Thank you ! to stay concerned :-)  So using your edit, can just : 1) create vector points from my tree raster layer, 2)  shift from a 6 m resolution region to 250m and 3) ask `r.in.xyz` to count points ? Anyway it's still strange this difference of cpu calculation time between these two use of `v.rast.stats`... something like a factor 10 (40 min with a grid from `v.mkgrid` and 400 min for my grid created with `r.to.vect`)

Comment: Concerning the speed of v.rast.stats: perhaps try with a different DB backend. I suppose that you use SQLite at time (check with db.connect -p), you may try PostgreSQL. Please note that v.rast.stats and r.to.vect do different things, so the performance cannot be the same.